# Having issues with understanding Array Size

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{char c[5];
scanf ("%s",&c);
printf("%s",c);}
```

So I have declared the array size to be 5.
But lets say when I type Elephant which is an 8 lettered word it still gets printed.Can someone explain why and also suggest what I should do so that the computer takes/considers my input only upto 5 characters.

Comment: `scanf ("%s",&c);` is wrong. A good compiler should give you a warning.

Comment: @YuHao: Since it's an array that we're dealing with, the values of `c` and `&c` are necessarily identical. Why would you expect a warning for that?

Comment: @barakmanos, after array to pointer decay, the values are identical, the types aren't. One is `char*` the other is `char (*)[5]`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: This is a call to `printf`. The compiler cannot (and does not need to) test the types of any of the arguments except for the first one (being `const char*`)!!!!!

Comment: For both, `printf` and `scanf` a format `%s` expects a `char*`. Good compilers notice that and warn you.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Well????? The type of the first argument (`"%s"`) is indeed a `const char*`! The type of the second argument (`&c`) can be anything as far as the compiler is concerned!!!

Comment: @barakmanos No, it's not, `c` is, or, to be precise, `c` decays to a pointer to `char`.

Comment: @barakmanos, who is talking about the type of the first argument? We are talking about the type of the second argument.

Comment: @YuHao: But what could the compiler do about it??? `scanf` takes `...` after the first argument, and `&c` is the second argument.

Comment: @JensGustedt: So am I. The compiler cannot issue a warning about the type of the second argument, because this type can be anything as far as the compiler is concerned (there is nothing in the prototype of functions `scanf` and `printf` that could indicate to the compiler what that type should be).

Comment: @barakmanos, try to compile such a thing with gcc and all warnings on, and you will see that a compiler can issue a warning. A compiler dosen't have to issue a warning (nobody said that), but it may. And good compilers do.

Comment: @barakmanos The compiler knows the format specifier is `"%s"`, right? A smart compiler then should give a warning on this.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I agree. But if I was a (good) compiler then I would identify `c` for being an array, in which case, the values of `c` and `&c` are necessarily identical, hence, whichever one used would make no runtime difference.

Comment: @barakmanos, no a "good" compiler can't "identify" `c` as being an array, because there is an imperative rule in C to convert an array to a pointer to the first element in such a context.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Are you following up on other answers of mine to down-vote me??? Wow, that's extremely mature! I thought we were having a cultural debate here.

Comment: @barakmanos, no I am following up what happened through the day, and perhaps you shouldn't go personal and talk about maturity.

Comment: @barakmanos You are wrong in two matters. First of all, most industry-class compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC, etc.) can and do warn about mismatching format string types. That's because although variadic functions don't know about the types they are called with **at an arbitrary point at runtime,** the compiler can (and needs to) deduce the types of arguments at the point where the call is made to a variadic function. (In fact, if it couldn't, then it couldn't perform the required conversions such as arithmetic promotion on the arguments.) Furthermore, `printf()` requires that a parameter...

Comment: @barakmanos ...for the `"%s"` conversion specifier be a pointer-to-character type, which `char (*)[3]` is not, hence the behavior is undefined. So, no matter how equal would the addresses `c` and `&c` be, a high-quality compiler would still warn upon detecting this instance of UB.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: I believe that the compiler makes the arithmetic conversions **regardless** of the contents of the format string (integer variables shorter than `int` are expanded to `int`, and `float` variables are expanded to `double`).

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, that is true, and it is exactly (half of) the point: even if the compiler does not know about the expected argument types, it performs the conversions. Now if it even **does** know about the types, it can warn.

Comment: @JensGustedt: "following up on what happened through the day" and down-voting an (unrelated) answer of mine two seconds after we happened to had a debate here? Yep, sounds very reliable... Am I to expect this kind of behavior after 4 years on SO? I should definitely start rehab before I get there myself. Thanks for opening up my eyes to that.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Got it. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is non-deterministic behavior. The array is 5 characters in memory, but scanf is not safe. It is putting all 8 characters into sequential memory starting at c[0] although 3 of the characters are technically not part of the array c. The last three characters may end up getting changed by some other application or function because they are not owned by the array c.

If you use the proper scan_s function it will throw an error when you try to do this. You should always use the "safe" functions for this.

Any array like this is actually a pointer to the first element of the array and the [5] indicates a 5 memory location offset from the first memory location defined by "c". You can freely set the number inside [] to any offset although it may go outside the bounds of what you allocated to c.

Comment: "If you use the proper scan_s function" - that's not "proper" by any means; it's a non-standard extension by Microsoft and one should not rely upon it in the general case. `scanf()` and all variations thereof are to be avoided anyway. There are **safe** input functions in the C standard library such as `fgets()`.

Comment: True. But he did ask to explain the allocation aspects of the array, not proper use of scanf. I'll leave it to him to fill the array, but a good understanding of how arrays work is essential to picking the correct function to use.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, `scanf_s` is part of the optional annex K of the latest C standard, C11.

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays have no bound-check. So basically, if you declare a 5-element array, you could store 100 elements in it and, if you are lucky (here, by lucky I mean to not overwrite some other, important things, that affect the program execution), it will work. But it is dangerous and wrong. It's your responsibility to make sure this will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

the variable c is allocated into the stack, when allocating space into the stack, the compiler may allocate more than what you're function really need so, that why when you write 8 character into the stack of the function main, you don't receive a segmentation fault.

you should change you're code and use :

```
fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);
```

Comment: Still `&c` has the wrong type. Either use `c` or `&c[0]`.